# How can I modify the property of ndb model through a webapp2 handler in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a python file and an html file that interact with each other through the jinja2 environment in a manner similar to the one in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction).

The following code controls the interaction between the html file and the python file:

```
 class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
        submission_query = Submission.query().order(-Submission.score)
        submissions = submission_query.fetch(10)

        template_values = {
            'Submission' : Submission,
            'submissions' : submissions,
        }

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/create', CreateSubmmission),
    ('/voteup', VoteUp),
], debug=True)
```

I have a ndb model as follows:

```
class Submission(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    placename = ndb.StringProperty()
    link = ndb.StringProperty()
    score = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

I have an html form to create a new Submission as follows:

```html
<form action="/create" method="post">
    add a new location: <br>
    your name:<div><textarea name="username" rows="2" cols="60"></textarea></div>
    placename:<div><textarea name="placename" rows="2" cols="60"></textarea></div>
    url:<div><textarea name="link" rows="2" cols="60"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Post"></div>
</form>
```

Using this request handler:

```
class CreateSubmmission(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        submission = Submission()
        submission.username = self.request.get('username')
        submission.placename = self.request.get('placename')
        submission.link = self.request.get('link')
        submission.score = 0
        submission.put()
        self.redirect('/')
```

I have a section in my html which prints out each Submission along with a button for upvoting it:

```html
{% for Submission in submissions %}
    <p>
        {{Submission.username}} posted:
        <strong><a href="{{Submission.link}}">{{Submission.placename}}</a></strong> <br>
        score:{{Submission.score}}<br>  
        <!--Vote up button-->
        <form action="/voteup?submission={{Submission}}" method="post">
            <div><input type="submit" value="voteup"></div>
        </form>
    </p><br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

The upvoting is handled by the following python class:

```
class VoteUp(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        submission = self.request.get('Submission')
        submission_key = submission.put()
        the_submission = submission_key.get()
        the_submission.score +=1
        the_submission.put()
        self.redirect('/')
```

When pressing the button, the value of the respective Submission's score attribute should increase by one.

The code is implemented on the website [sunlit-hook-91816.appspot.com](http://sunlit-hook-91816.appspot.com). As can be seen on that site, pressing the upvote button generates the following error:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sunlit-hook-91816/1.383863233180213164/guestbook.py", line 52, in post
    submission_key = submission.put()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'put'
```

It appears that the VoteUp class is somehow unable to modify the value of Submission.score.

I am using the information found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities) but I can't figure out how to correctly apply it this problem. Can anyone tell me of a way to make the VoteUp class modify the Submission.score?

Comment: In the future, it might be more useful to explain some of the steps you've tried instead of just linking to a remote resource. Sometimes those links go stale, and it's also easier for users here if they can just read a summary of your steps and their results. The advice here on writing a minimal, complete, verifiable example may help you write clearer questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

You should start by investigating the error message. What type of object do you expect `submission` to be in the VoteUp `post(self)` method? Right now it's a string.

Comment: get a debugger so you can step through the code. you can't put strings into the DB like that, as inquiryqueue notes.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Submission object like it can be passed along between html/python code but it can't, you must add a reference in the form and dereference it back in you server.

Do this in the vote form:

```html
<form action="/voteup?submission={{Submission.key.urlsafe()}}" method="post">
    <div><input type="submit" value="voteup"></div>
</form>
```

We're getting the key of the submission in a [format safe for http transport](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_urlsafe), so it can arrive back to the server unaltered.

Now when processing the vote, we can recreate the key and get the correct object:

```python
class VoteUp(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        submission = self.request.get('submission')
        submission_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=submission)
        the_submission = submission_key.get()
        the_submission.score +=1
        the_submission.put()
        self.redirect('/')
```

As you can see we're just recreating the key based on the formatted string we printed in the form.

Another way you could do this to make it even better is to use an extra input in the form:

```html
<form action="/voteup" method="post">
    <input name="submission" type="hidden" value="{{Submission.key.urlsafe()}}">
    <div><input type="submit" value="voteup"></div>
</form>
```

Your code will work the same way, but I find it easier to read and maintain.